# Retrieving Contact Object By Address?

Tags: rest-api

I'm trying to find if it's possible to use SalesforceIQ's API to retrieve a Contact object by address. According to the documentation I can retrieve an object by Id, email or phone number. But can I use contact address for this purpose?

I have already tried:

```
curl 'https://api.salesforceiq.com/v2/contacts?properties.address=some_address'
```

But I'm getting following:

{"statusCode":400,"errorMessage":"Invalid Query Parameter(s): properties.address","userMessage":"Bad Request"}

Or maybe there are other ways to do that?

Comment: Contact object does not have "Address" as property. Instead MailingAddress and OtherAddress.

Answer (score 2):

Address field is a compound field and I don't think you can access it directly even with api.
You can try using "City", "State" and others to do data query.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.202.0.api.meta/api/compound_fields_address.htm

Comment: can you provide an example, because every time when I'm trying to get contact by 'city' I receive "Invalid Query Parameter(s)".

Comment: Try with MailingCity or OtherCity.